# Как haskell получает тип для ((sequence .) . fmap)?

Tags: haskell

Пытаюсь понять как работает вывод типа в haskell на конкретном примере, а именно `((sequence .) . fmap)`. Для упрощения я решил получить типы для отдельных подвыражений - тут всё прошло гладко и я получил такие же типы, что и ghci:

```
-- Сначала тип для (sequence .):
(.)      :: (b -> c) ->
            (a -> b) -> 
            (a -> c)

sequence :: (Traversable t, Monad m) => t (m a)  -> m (t a)

b ~ t (m a)
c ~ m (t a)

(sequence .)  :: (a1 -> t (m a2)) ->
                 (a1 -> m (t a2))
```

Всё чётко, такой же тип возвращает и ghci. Теперь определим тип для `(sequence .) .` aka `(.) (sequence .)`:

```
(.)           :: (b -> c) ->
                 (a -> b) -> 
                 (a -> c)

(sequence .)  :: (a1 -> t (m a2)) ->
                 (a1 -> m (t a2))

b ~ (a1 -> t (m a2))
c ~ (a1 -> m (t a2))

(.) (sequence .) :: (a -> (a1 -> t (m a2))) ->
                    (a -> (a1 -> m (t a2)))
```

Снова всё ок, такой же тип возвращает ghci. Теперь финальная часть, определим тип для `(.) (sequence .) (fmap)` (для упрощения символы в типе для `fmap` изменены):

```
fmap             :: Functor f => (z -> u) -> f z -> f u

(.) (sequence .) :: (a -> (a1 -> t (m a2))) ->
                    (a -> (a1 -> m (t a2))) 

a  ~ (z -> u)
a1 ~ f z
t (m a2) ~ f u

(.) (sequence .) (fmap) :: ((z -> u) -> (f z -> m (t a2))
```

Полученный тип несколько отличается от возвращаемого ghci:

```
Prelude Control.Monad> :t (sequence .) . fmap
(sequence .) . fmap
  :: (Traversable t, Monad m) => (a1 -> m a2) -> t a1 -> m (t a2)
```

Собственно вопрос - почему `u` ghci раскрыл в `m a2`? Понятно, что это следует из замены `t (m a2) ~ f u`
Вопрос два - почему `f z` ghci меняет на `t a1` (короче говоря, почему подменяется тип структуры?)

Comment: Из `t (m a2) ~ f u` следует что `t ~ f`. На первый вопрос вы сами ответили.

Comment: @talex, просто непонятно, в каком случае мы продолжаем замену, в каком - оставляем как есть. Причём как я думал, замена производится всегда в одном направлении, а здесь мы делаем обратную замену -- `u -> (m a2)`

Comment: Всегда осуществляем. Компилятор придумывает свои имена, но конкретные имена не важны. Важна структура.

Answer (score 1):

Упростим определения до:

```
foo :: (a -> a1 -> t (m a2)) ->
       (a -> a1 -> m (t a2)) 

fmap :: (z -> u) -> f z -> f u
```

Теперь рассмотрим как сопостовляются типы при вызове `foo fmap`

- `a -> a1 -> t (m a2)` соответствует `(z -> u) -> f z -> f u`
- `a` соответствует `z -> u`
- `a1` соответствует `f z`
- `t (m a2)` соответствует `f u`

  - `t` соответствует `f`
  - `m a2` соответствует `u`

Это возможно только если `u` имеет форму `c1 c2`. Произведем замену.

```
fmap :: (z -> с1 с2) -> f z -> f (с1 с2)
```

Повторим попытку сопоставить.

- `a -> a1 -> t (m a2)` соответствует `(z -> с1 с2) -> f z -> f (с1 с2)`
- `a` соответствует `z -> с1 с2`
- `a1` соответствует `f z`
- `t (m a2)` соответствует `f с1 с2`

  - `t` соответствует `f`
  - `m a2` соответствует `с1 с2`

    - `m` соответствует `c1`
    - `a2` соответствует `c2`

Теперь подставим найденные соответствия в оставшуюся не сопоставленой часть `foo`: `a -> a1 -> m (t a2)`

- `a` заменим на `z -> с1 с2`: `(z -> с1 с2) -> a1 -> m (t a2)`
- `a1` заменим на `f z`: `(z -> с1 с2) -> f z -> m (t a2)`
- `m` заменим на `c1`: `(z -> с1 с2) -> f z -> c1 (t a2)`
- `t` заменим на `f`: `(z -> с1 с2) -> f z -> c1 (f a2)`
- `a2` заменим на `c2`: `(z -> с1 с2) -> f z -> c1 (f c2)`

Получим тип структурно эквивалентный тому что требовалось получить: `(a1 -> m0 a0) -> t0 a1 -> m0 (t0 a0)`

`